# jQuery 2.1.0 | Reorder li based on separate delimited string

Tags: arrays, sorting, html-lists, substring

I need to **reorder** li containing unique same-length text based on position of identical unique same-length semicolon-delimited text found in a separate string, as in following example:

***li elements ...***

```
<ul>
<li><span>28dg4</span></li>
<li><span>jjk63</span></li>
<li><span>HN3gE</span></li>
<li><span>k213C</span></li>
</ul>
```

***... sorted by order of semicolon delimited substrings (left to right),***

```
<div id="string">HN3gE;28dg4;k213C;jjk63</div>
```

***... must reorder li like this:***

```
<ul>
<li><span>HN3gE</span></li>
<li><span>28dg4</span></li>
<li><span>k213C</span></li>
<li><span>jjk63</span></li>
</ul>
```

I've set up a fiddle but can't formulate the approrpiate comparison function (new to me):
http://jsfiddle.net/ysec0ydp/16/

Maybe I cannot use sort and should use something else? I haven't found anything on here or elsewhere that does specifically what I want  ;-(
Thx for pointers.

**UPDATE**

The following code outputs the proper order of string, but doesn't display as appended li:

```
<div id="string">tree$1234567890;boat$4567321890;9876512340;1736925408</div>

<ul>
    <li><span>1234567890</span></li>
    <li><span>1736925408</span></li>
    <li><span>4567321890</span></li>
    <li><span>9876512340</span></li>
</ul>

var ul = $('ul');
var li = ul.children("li");

var my_list = li.map(function() {
return $(this).find('span').text();
}).get();

var my_string = $.map($("#string").text().split(/;/), function (t) {
return t.replace(/^.*\$/, "");
});

li.detach();
temp = [];


for (i = 0; i < my_string.length; i++) {
for (j = 0; j < my_list.length; j++) {
if ( my_string[i] == my_list[j] ) {
temp.push(my_list[j]);
}
}
}

$("ul").append( temp );

//  RESULT is one li: 1234567890456732189098765123401736925408

//  instead of the 4 reordered li: 1234567890
                                   4567321890
                                   9876512340
                                   1736925408
```

How can this be fixed? See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ysec0ydp/19/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
var orderBy = $('#string').text().split(';');

var $newUl = $('<ul></ul>');

var $myList = $('#my-list');    // gave id="my-list" to your list to identify it.
orderBy.forEach(function(key){
    $newUl.append($myList.find('li').filter(function(idx, li){ return $(li).text() === key; }).detach());
});

$myList.append($newUl.html());
```

I took the liberty of giving an id to your list to identify it.

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/rpxr2k27/).

Comment: Woah! Couldn't have figured it out like yours! Question: Does your code preserve all binded/linked functions the original dynamically created ul list elements would have before? I used "detach' for this and so do you, but still asking...? (see Update).

Comment: If you have delegated your events to the `ul`, then it would preserve the events. Also, all data bound to the elements is preserved when you use detach().